# ngFor take last created Array by parent ngFOR

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to connect material tabs with ngFor that create arrays for child ngFor.

So start from beginning:

```
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs ">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>
    <div *ngFor="let event of tabs">
        <event-thumbnail [eve]="event"></event-thumbnail>
    </div>  
</mat-tab>
```

First step I make is to create a "tabs" labels

```
        this.asyncTabs = [
        {label: 'A-B', content: this.getTabContent(10)},
        {label: 'C-D', content: this.getTabContent(5)},
        {label: 'E-F', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'G-H', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'I-J', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'K-L', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'M-N', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'O-P', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'R-S', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'T-U', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'W-X', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
        {label: 'Y-Z', content: this.getTabContent(0)},
    ]
```

And my getTabContent() function is filtering some Array based on condition and return `tabs` array with filtered object.

```
    getTabContent(condition){
     this.tabs = this.events.filter(x=> x.price == condition)
     return this.tabs 
    }
```

after that, I want to run child ngFor `*ngFor="let event of tabs"` that should populate the content of each tab

the problem is that the second ngFor takes always the last `tabs` array created by the first ngFor and all tabs are populated by the same data

New Array configuration `tabs: IEvent[] = []`

Can anyone help me with that, please?
P.S I know that I can use list filtering but I need to do it in that way

Comment: I recommend adding a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com), to see if you can recreate outside of your env and more importantly so when can help work through this faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly use `tab.content`, no need of `this.tab`. Everytime you run the `getTabContent` function, it will replace `this.tab` values, so it will always hold the last ran value.

```html
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs ">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>
    <div *ngFor="let event of tab.content">
        <event-thumbnail [eve]="event"></event-thumbnail>
    </div>  
</mat-tab>
```

```js
getTabContent(condition){
   return this.events.filter(x=> x.price === condition);
}
```

eg: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3w1pv

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell which "tab" you want to iterate on with an index:

```
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs; let i = index">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>
    <div *ngFor="let event of tabs[i]">
        <event-thumbnail [eve]="event"></event-thumbnail>
    </div>  
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. I didn't check that but probably the reason for that is in my example I used 2 different arrays but index work only if the second array are the element of the first array. In my example, I have element `tab` but in the second I use `tabs` but I should use `tabs[i]`. But thanks for help and suggestions